# basic reducer possibly mutating app state

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, immutability, reducers

I am using Redux spread operator to hopefully mantain the state as immutable objects.

However, i am managing to make the most simple unit test fail.

I assume the error probably has to do with immutables, but am i not using the spread operator correctly?

Here is my unit test:

```html
describe('app logic', () => {
  it('initialises app', () => {
    const newState = reducer(INITIAL_STATE, {type: "NEXT"})
    const expectState = {
      start: true,
      render_component: null,
      requests: {},
      results: {},
    }
    console.log('newState', newState)
    console.log('expected state', expectState)
    expect(newState).to.equal(expectState)
  })
})
```

and here is my reducer

```html
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  start: false,
  render_component: null,
  requests: {},
  results: {}
}

export const next = (state) => {
  if (state === INITIAL_STATE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      start: true,
    }
  }
  return state
}

export function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'NEXT':
      return next(state)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I print the two objects, and they look the same.
i get the error :

1) app logic initialises app:

```
  AssertionError: expected { Object (start, render_component, ...) } to equal { Object (start, render_component, ...) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly which testing library you are using, but usually a name like `.equal` is used to test strict equality ( `===`  ), which means (at least in the case of objects) that the two things being compared must actually reference the exact same object. So, for example,

```
const original = { a: 1 }; // creates a new object, assign it
const testMe = { a: 1 }; // creates another new object, assign it
console.log( original === testMe )   // false
```

evaluates to false, because while the objects have the same *content*, they do not reference the exact same object. They are separate, independently created, objects that happen to have the same content. Compare that to

```
const original = {a: 1}; // create a new object
const testMe = original;  // create another reference to the same object
console.log( original === testMe );  // true
```

So when you return

```
return {
  ...state,
  start: true,
}
```

you are creating and returning a new object, so it naturally can **not** reference the same object that you created and assigned to the variable name `expectedState`.

If what you are interested in is not strict equality, but rather just that the content in the two objects are the same, there exists other methods than `.equal`, usually named something with `deep` (since they go deep into the objects/arrays/whatever to check if the values are the same).

Chai.js has examples of both `expect(x).to.equal(y)` and `expect(x).to.deep.equal(y)` in their docs: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal

Your testing library probably has very similar, if not identical, syntax.